# Extracing words that start with '#' from a string into a stringstream- C++

Tags: c++, string, istringstream

I am trying to write a program that will return words that start with the symbol # from a string.
For example:
A string such as "I like #tacos and #pizza" would return: #tacos #pizza

This is my current code:

```
int main(void){
    string myString = "I like #tacos and #pizza";
    std::istringstream iss(myString);
    while(iss >> myString){
        int i = 0;
        if(myString[i] == '#'){
            iss >> myString;
        }
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << myString;
}
```

However, this only returns one word that starts with a hashtag. Any help as to what I can change in the code?

Comment: There's only one output call (`<<`) and its not in any loop, so obviously this will always print exactly one thing -- the last word extracted into myString.  What are you expecting to be output?

Comment: The second `iss >> myString;` shouldn't even be there. The `std::cout << myString;` should be moved up into the loop to replace it. Further, `i` seems enitrely pointless here. Either use `myString[0]` or use `myString.front()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check the string's first character with `front` or `myString[0]`, and print the output in the loop. Your original code will at most print once so I move the print statement into the loop.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(void) {
  std::string myString = "I like #tacos and #pizza";
  std::istringstream iss(myString);
  while (iss >> myString) {
    if (myString.front() == '#') {
      std::cout << myString << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/33aaa1x3M)